# Situar elemento atrás

Tags: html, css

Estoy buscando una forma de colocar un elemento que se vea de la siguiente manera:

[image: resultado esperado]

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora:

```css
.section-mobile {
    /* background: #F8F9FA; */
    background: #004987;
}

.imagen-data .img-mobile {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Data Planning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="section-mobile d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-block p-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-9 imagen-data">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" class="img-mobile">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo la diferencia entre la foto y el codigo.

Comment: @alanfcm en la foto, el cuadrado esta picado por la mitad por asi decirlo, significa que se ubica solo en la parte azul, y en el codigo, se ubica tanto en la parte azul como en la blanca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que buscas es `overflow: hidden;` asi:

```css
.section-mobile {
    /* background: #F8F9FA; */
    background: #004987;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imagen-data .img-mobile {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -200px;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <title>Data Planning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="section-mobile d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-block p-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-9 imagen-data">
                    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x400" alt="" class="img-mobile">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```